# CTRL meta key 'sticky' in GUIs over X11 forwarding from CentOS to fedora

Tags: ssh, fedora, centos, x11, gui

Despite numerous problems, I managed to get X11 forwarding working from a SSH server running on a CentOS host to a Fedora client (changing various settings and finally fixing it by installing a package for authentication). The program in question is Geany. It acts as though the CTRL meta key was always pressed, not allowing me to enter characters normally.

- What can I do about this?
- What information should I provide?

Here is exactly what I mean:

```
ssh -XY4 -i ... user@host
geany
```

Within Geany every keystroke is processed as if with the CTRL modifier.

Comment: Can you show a little more details of what you're doing? It's a little hard to follow exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What details should I provide, exactly?

Comment: Can you show a command line example?